# Process writing after it's finished?

Tags: java, process, java.util.scanner

I have a Process started like that:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "mongod | tee /tmp/logfile.txt");
```

This process, when it's interrupted, gracefully ends, writing to the output stream "dbexit: really exiting now"

So later, I want to kill it:

```
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream()
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter(Pattern.quote("dbexit: really exiting now"));
//pid taken from grep
Shell.runShellCommand("kill -2 " + pid).waitFor();
scanner.next()
```

This *always* runs successfully on my machine. But almost never on CI server. scanner.next() throws:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
```

So it seems like the process ended (or at least closed it's InputStream) before writing "dbexit: really exiting now". But this text is present at the end of `/tmp/logfile.txt`. Is it possible that process InputStream was closed, while it was still writing? And that it was written to the file?

Comment: why do you have scanner.next() after kill command?

Comment: Because it's blocking. It would never get to "kill" if scanner.next() was first.

Comment: So, Shell.runShellCommand("kill -2 " + pid).waitFor(); blocks until it kills it? Are you running kill from the same JVM? or from diff. JVM instance?

Comment: No, scanner.next() is blocking. Shell.runShellCommand("kill -2 " + pid).waitFor(); waits only for exit from it's own shell. Everything on one JVM instance.

Comment: Why don't you operate on the output stream of process ?

Comment: @Vash He does. The doc for the Process.getInputStream reads: The stream obtains data piped from the standard output stream of the process.

Answer (score 1):

The input stream is buffered. You read data from the buffer, which were written before the process get killed.

Comment: So some sort of flush call needed before stream destroyed.

Comment: But when I get the exception, doesn't it mean the stream is closed? And if it is closed, shouldn't it be flushed before it's closed? And shouldn't the process do it?